How to set a KMS CMK for an existing DynamoDB table using CDK written in Python
I have a few tables already existing in DynamoDB. Some of them are empty and some may have a few test records.
I am trying to add a new kms cmk to one of these existing tables using the code below in python.
    table_encryption_key= kms.Key(
        self, "kms-cmk",
        alias= "myapp/appkey/cmk",
        description= "CMK for encrypting existing DynamoDB table",
        enabled= True,
        removal_policy= RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,  
        key_spec= kms.KeySpec.SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT
    )

    table_ref =  dynamodb.TableV2.from_table_name(
        self, "table_name_rd", "rd_store"
    )
    table_ref.encryption = dynamodb.TableEncryption.CUSTOMER_MANAGED
    table_ref.encryption_key = table_encryption_key

I get the error can't set attribute 'encryption_key'
This what I am referring to for documentation. What am I missing?

You cannot modify existing resources with Cloudformation/CDK.
